# Is there a name to describe this type of street?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe a street type.  The street is found in city outskirts and the suburbs in the US.  The street is (for the most part) three car widths wide.  Parking is only on one side.  So really if people are parked on that one side then people that are going in that direction have to wait if there is oncoming traffic or passing is very narrow/dangerous.

Example:  Street goes south to north.  Parking is on right side (or east).  The people going north have the cars in their way and must navigate around them.  The people going south have the right of way.  Do we call this a South Through street?

Comment: Why  “North Through” rather than “South Through” when southbound cars have the right of way?

Comment: @jwpat7 - That was a bit confusing so I edited.

Comment: Do you have a label for this in your native language, or if your native language is AmE, do you want a technical term for this or an informal one?

Answer (score 1):

In American English, the names for road types are not that specific.  A road like you describe would simply be called a "street" or perhaps a "two-lane road" (because there are two lanes to accommodate moving traffic -- one in each direction).  These names would be correct even if there were parking on both sides.  If there were no parking on either side (as in a more rural area), it would be called a "two-lane highway."